# how to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/AbstractDriverOptions?

Tags: selenium, geb

I am trying to run a basic geb program on my new laptop and I am continuously getting this error. Below is the error and pom I am using. Please help me if I am doing something wrong.

POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-M3-groovy-3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gebish</groupId>
    <artifactId>geb-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gebish</groupId>
    <artifactId>geb-spock</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
</dependency>
```

Error:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Archived non-system classes
> are disabled because the java.system.class.loader property is
> specified (value = "groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader"). To use archived
> non-system classes, this property must not be set Caught:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/openqa/selenium/remote/AbstractDriverOptions
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/openqa/selenium/remote/AbstractDriverOptions  at
> org.apache.groovy.util.concurrent.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.lambda$compute$0(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java:788)
> at
> org.apache.groovy.util.concurrent.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.compute(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java:800)
> at
> org.apache.groovy.util.concurrent.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java:777)
> at GebExample1.run(GebExample1.groovy:5)    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.AbstractDriverOptions  ... 7 more

Comment: Can you share you code to much more understand?

Comment: Add this [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver/4.0.0-alpha-6) to your POM and check if it works

Comment: Thank you Wilfred. Added the dependency and it worked fine.